# quick view popup not working in ipad/iphone?

Tags: magento-1.9

I create quick view for my site but its shows below error in ipad/iphone

```
magento XMLHttpRequest cannot load . No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.  is therefore not allowed access.
```

i use
                       `<a href="#" data-fancybox-type="ajax" onclick="QuickView('<?php echo Mage::getUrl('index/view/id/'.$_product->getId());?>');return false;" title="<?php echo $this->__('Quick View') ?>" class="button detail-bnt"><span><?php echo $this->__('Quick View') ?></span></a>`

Comment: please contact to extension support they are solve your problem

Comment: its own extension...

Comment: ohooo then you have to update the code

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about third party extension

Comment: Any idea about error?

Comment: Do you have different url for the mobile site?

Comment: Please specify a extension name or give your live site url.

Comment: @ravi check this url http://robbshop.jaccoermers.nl/ kindly reply me ...

Comment: this was working very well. check your browser issue.

Comment: @ravi its not seen in iphone.

Comment: ya man but after select quickview long process not display anything in ipad. generally ipad and iphone on this was not display in theme. on ipad on hover display select very difficult. so u add icon for quickview near wishlist see next lavel magento theme. not comment use u can  chat with me useing stack over chat option http://chat.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @ravi can u tell me how to add & which file i add access-control

Answer (score 1):

There have Two right answer:

[1) No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)

[2) No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present on the requested resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20881532/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)

```
Instead of using setHeader method I have used addHeader.
```

> response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
>
> response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
>   "http://www.example.com");

On your site this was working
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error means: You need to add an Access-Control-Allow-Origin HTTP Header.